# Use Lambda expression to find all objects with matching id

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm working with Lambda expressions for the first time and trying to understand how to do this. I'm following a pattern that exists already in this test file, but my call has an extra layer of complexity in that I need to look inside each of the objects to select all that have an id that will be provided at the time of the test.

*myobject.cs*

```
public class myObject
{
    public myObject()
    {
        this.id = Guid.Empty;
        this.poolId = Guid.Empty;
        this.name = string.Empty;
        this.URL = string.Empty;
    }

    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public Guid poolId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }

}
```

*testfile.cs*

```
Mock<IMyObjectRepository> mock = new Mock<IMyObjectRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict);

List<myObject> objects = new List<myObject>();

mock.Setup(r => r.LoadByPoolId(It.IsAny<Guid>()))
    .Returns<IEnumerable<myObject>>(objList => objects.Where(obj => objList.Contains(obj.id));
```

The problem is, this only searches surface level objects, it does not search the properties of the objects. What's the piece I'm missing to select all `myObjects` with a matching id?

The repository interface

```
public interface IMyObjectRepository
{
    void Put(myObject object)
    void Delete(Guid appId);
    myObject Load(Guid appId)
    IEnumerable<myObject> LoadByPoolId(Guid poolId);
}
```

Comment: Show the definition of the class/interface being mocked. From your current code we are left guessing what it is. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I didn't include it because I really didn't think it would help, but there you go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using provided example

```
var mock = new Mock<IMyObjectRepository>();

var objects = new List<myObject>();
//...populate objects

// access invocation arguments when returning a value
mock.Setup(r => r.LoadByPoolId(It.IsAny<Guid>()))
    .Returns((Guid arg) => objects.Where(obj => obj.poolId == arg));
```

In the `Returns` expression the provided argument is passed to the expression used to filter the `objects` list.

Reference : [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Comment: Thank you for that, my closest attempt was SO close, but i had Returns<IEnumerable<myObject>> in there. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to help. take some time and review the documentation. Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

LINQ's `Where` method accepts a lambda expression that allows you to perform any check you wish.  Write an expression that evaluates to true for rows you wish to include and false otherwise.

In your case the expression would be `o.id == targetGUID` so just insert it into the lambda body:

```
var filteredList = list.Where(o => o.id == targetGUID);
```